# compare two lists and print out unequal elements

Tags: python, list, equality

I have two lists in the following format:

```
list1 = ['A','B','C','D']
list2 = [('A',1),('B',2),('C',3)]
```

I want to compare the two lists and print out a third list which will have those elements present in list1 but not in list2 and I want to compare only the list2[i][0] elements.

I tried the below code:

```
fin = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]
```

But it prints all the elements in list1. I want the output in the above case to be :

```
fin = ['D']
```

Could somebody please suggest how to do that? 
Also, I do not want to convert my 2D array list2 to 1D array.

Comment: Are the items in each list sorted?

Comment: Yes, only the corresponding elements in each list should be compared

Answer (score 6):

Use the set difference.

```
set(list1) - set(i[0] for i in list2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as well (you need to compare i with the first element of each tuple in list2):

```
fin = [i for i in list1 if i not in map(lambda(x,_):x,list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about nested comprehensions:

```
fin = [a for a in list1 if a not in [b for b,_ in list2]]
```