# Compare flat list and nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to compare the two lists below. `edges` is a list of tuples while `b_edge` is a nested list of tuples. what i want is to append `edges[i][2] to all b_edge[i][j] if b_edge[i][j] == edge[0:2].`

Here are the lists:

```
edges = [('1.0', '2.0',{'length':0.35}),('2.0', '3.0',{'length':0.46,}),('3.0', '4.0', {'length':0.49}),(4.0, 5.0,{'length':0.22}),('5.0', '6.0',{'length':0.54}),('6.0', '7.0', {'length':0.49}),('7.0', '8.0',{'length':0.22}),(5.0, 6.0,{'length':0.54})]

b_edge = [[('1.0', '2.0'), ('2.0', '3.0'), ('3.0', '4.0')], [('5.0', '6.0'), ('6.0', '7.0'), ('7.0', '8.0')]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[('1.0', '2.0', {'length': 0.35}), ('2.0', '3.0', {'length': 0.46}), ('3.0', '4.0', {'length': 0.49})], [('5.0', '6.0', {'length': 0.35}), ('6.0', '7.0', {'length': 0.46}), ('7.0', '8.0', {'length': 0.49})]
```

I tried this:

```
result = []
for j in b_edge:
    temp = []
    for l,k in enumerate(j):
        if j[l][0:2] == edges[l][:2]:
            temp.append(k + (edges[l][2],))
    result.append(temp)
print 'result', result
```

and have also checked these answers on SO [compare two lists and print out unequal elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624407/compare-two-lists-and-print-out-unequal-elements) and similar question but they dont quite match what I want.

and got this result:

```
[[('1.0', '2.0', {'length': 0.35}), ('2.0', '3.0', {'length': 0.46}), ('3.0', '4.0', {'length': 0.49})], []]
```

It seems to append the dictionary only to the first element in the nested list for the second it just outputs an empty list.

Thank you.

Comment: @timgeb, compare both list and append dictionary in the first list to the matching elements in the second. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered putting your edges into a dictionary? Something like `{("1.0", "2.0"): 0.35, ("2.0", "3.0"): 0.46`}`. It would make your problem simpler, and more intuitive.

Comment: I would have loved to but this is the data format required for what I am doing

Comment: `edges_dict = {(edge[0], edge[1]): edge[2]['length'] for edge in edges}`

Comment: where does `('5.0', '6.0', {'length': 0.35})` come from in your expected output?

Comment: comes from the first list named edges

Comment: I mean what is the relationship between `('1.0', '2.0',{'length':0.35})` and `('5.0', '6.0', {'length': 0.35})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = b_edge
tmp_dict = { (i[0],i[1]): i[2] for i in edges }
for index_j, j in enumerate(b_edge):
    for index_i, i in enumerate(j):
        if i in tmp_dict:
            result[index_j][index_i] = result[index_j][index_i] + (tmp_dict[i],)
```

I created a dictionary to map your tuples to your {"length"} dictionary and used that to produce your desired output.

Comment: this is close to it but can you help me have the out ion a nested list format like so: [[('1.0', '2.0', {'length': 0.35})], ('2.0', '3.0', {'length': 0.46}), ('3.0', '4.0', {'length': 0.49}), [('5.0', '6.0', {'length': 0.54}), ('6.0', '7.0', {'length': 0.49}), ('7.0', '8.0', {'length': 0.22})] Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One liner of glory:

```
result = [[edge for edge in edges if (edge[0], edge[1]) in edge_group] for edge_group in b_edge]
```

The word edge feels weird in my mouth now.

Also, I know you said that the data is how you get it, but I would personally still change it to a dictionary like so:

```
edge_lengths = {(edge[0], edge[1]): edge[2]['length'] for edge in edges}
# Gives you:
# {('1.0', '2.0'): 0.35, ('3.0', '4.0'): 0.49, ... , ('5.0', '6.0'): 0.54}

# Get lengths
print [[edge_lengths[edge] for edge in edge_group] for edge_group in b_edge]
# [[0.35, 0.46, 0.49], [0.54, 0.49, 0.22]]
```

Of course it's up to you :)

Comment: this is close to it but can you help me have the out ion a nested list format like so: [[('1.0', '2.0', {'length': 0.35})], ('2.0', '3.0', {'length': 0.46}), ('3.0', '4.0', {'length': 0.49}), [('5.0', '6.0', {'length': 0.54}), ('6.0', '7.0', {'length': 0.49}), ('7.0', '8.0', {'length': 0.22})] Thank you

Comment: Thanks @pokey, your one line is glorious indeed

Comment: Thanks @Nobi, one day I shall show it to my grandchildren.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a mapping of number-tuples to the length like this:

```
>>> num_to_len = {x[0:2]:x[2] for x in edges}
>>> num_to_len
{(4.0, 5.0): {'length': 0.22}, ('3.0', '4.0'): {'length': 0.49}, (5.0, 6.0): {'length': 0.54}, ('1.0', '2.0'): {'length': 0.35}, ('6.0', '7.0'): {'length': 0.49}, ('2.0', '3.0'): {'length': 0.46}, ('7.0', '8.0'): {'length': 0.22}, ('5.0', '6.0'): {'length': 0.54}}
```

Then build your desired result like this:

```
>>> [[x if x not in num_to_len else x+(num_to_len[x],) for x in b_edge[0]]]
[[('1.0', '2.0', {'length': 0.35}), ('2.0', '3.0', {'length': 0.46}), ('3.0', '4.0', {'length': 0.49})]]
```

Note that wrapping everything in another list, as you specified, is probably not neccesary. So unless you have a good reason, skip the outermost brackets in the list comprehension.